How can I add multiple conditions in a LINQ Select to return values based on an enum?
I'm working on a LINQ query where I need to select values from a data source based on the value of an enum (ConversationRole). I want to return different user IDs based on whether the ConversationRole is Sender or Receiver.
I tried using a ternary operator in my LINQ Select statement to select either ReceiverUserId or SenderUserId based on the ConversationRole enum value. The problem is the userId being returned is incorrect. The Where clause is correct, but then the condition of selecting either the ReceiverUserId or the SenderUserId is what is not working correctly
var datasource = _context.Conversations.AsQueryable();

var query = await datasource.Where(id => id.Id == conversationid)
    .Select(role => 
        role.ConversationRole == ConversationRole.Sender ? role.ReceiverUserId 
        : role.ConversationRole == ConversationRole.Receiver ? role.SenderUserId
        : ""
    )
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();


If  role.ConversationRole == ConversationRole.Sender is true then it should return role.SenderUserId correct ? If yes, you have to exchange role.SenderUserId  with role.ReceiverUserId and vice-versa

not working correctly -- Please describe what is "correct".

How specifically is it not working?

With projection it's can be preferable to return raw values then do the conversion/selection outside of the Linq-to-SQL. EF is looking for the expression to say "get me columns A, B, and C", but that link expression says "Get me B if A = this, or C if A = that". It's possible that the EF provider is having trouble working out to fetch A, B, and C to work that out correctly:
var details = await datasource.Where(id => id.Id == conversationid)
    .Select(role => new 
    {
        role.ConversationRole, 
        role.ReceiverUserId, 
        role.SenderUserId
    ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

switch (details?.ConversionRole)
{
    case ConversationRole.Sender:
        return details.ReceiverUserId;
    case ConversationRole.Receiver:
        return details.SenderUserId;
    default:
        return string.Empty;
}

Selecting the raw values makes it easy to inspect details in the event you get a row/combination you don't expect.  If your example was a simplification and instead you were populating a value in a DTO/ViewModel with the ternary expression you can instead select the raw values into the DTO and have the DTO expose a computed value:
// Inside the DTO class, include the ConversionRole, ReceiverUserId, and SenderUserId properties populated by EF.

public string TargetUserId => ConversionRole == ConversationRole.Sender
    ? details.ReceiverUserId
    : ConversionRole == ConversionRole.Receiver
        ? details.SenderUserId
        : string.Empty;


That worked, thank you bro

@StevePy's answer may be an option, but what I would do is the following:
First of all, I would avoid using ternary conditionals with more than one conditional. I would limit myself to only the format A ? B : C, and not things like A ? B : C ? D : E... You can go on like this to infinity, and while it makes the code simpler and with fewer lines, it's difficult to read. Personally, I'm lazy to read this.
Seconds, I would encapsulate the database query with a function that would return the desired object or columns. Then, in my code I would get the object according to what I need. Here is an example.
public class ConversationDetails {

    public string ConversationRole { get; set; }
    public int ReceiverUserId { get; set; }
    public int SenderUserId { get; set; }

}

// In your class or your code:
public async Task<ConversationDetails?> GetConversationDetailsAsync(int conversationId) {

    var details = await _dbContext.YourDataSource.Where(role => role.Id == conversationId).Select(

        role => new ConversationDetails {

                ConversationRole = role.ConversationRole,
                ReceiverUserId = role.ReceiverUserId,
                SenderUserId = role.SenderUserId

        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

}

// Now, you can get the columns you want.
void main() {

    // TODO - Your code.
    var details = await GetConversationDetailsAsync(userID);

    // You can use a switch/case or if/else if.
    switch (details?.ConversionRole) {

        case ConversationRole.Sender:
            return details.ReceiverUserId;

        case ConversationRole.Receiver:
            return details.SenderUserId;

        default:
            return string.Empty;

    }

}

